# Multiplication on command line terminal

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I'm using a serial terminal to provide input into our lab experiment. I found that using

```
$ echo "5X5"
```

just returns a string of `"5X5"`. Is there a command to execute a multiplication operation?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Yes, you can use [bash's built-in Arithmetic Expansion `$(( ))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) to do some simple maths

```
$ echo "$((5 * 5))"
25
```

Check the [Shell Arithmetic section in the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) for a complete list of operators.

For sake of completeness, as other pointed out, if you need arbitrary precision, [`bc`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bc/) or [`dc`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/dc/) would be better.

Answer (score 51):

For more advanced and precise math consider using bc(1).

```
echo "3 * 2.19" | bc -l 
6.57
```

Comment: this is solution which works with floating point numbers

Answer (score 22):

#### Internal Methods

Bash supports [arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) with `$(( expression ))`. For example:

```
$ echo $(( 5 * 5 ))
25
```

#### External Methods

A number of utilities provide arithmetic, including *bc* and *expr*.

```
$ echo '5 * 5' | /usr/bin/bc
25

$ /usr/bin/expr 5 \* 5
25
```

Answer (score 18):

The classical solution is:

```
 expr 5 \* 5
```

`expr` will only work with integer operands.  Another nice option is:

```
 echo 5 5\*p | dc
```

`dc` can be made to work with non-integer operands.

Comment: `dc` works with floats. Try `echo '4 k 50 7 / p' | dc`. The output is `7.1428`. The `k` command sets the precision.

Comment: @Dennis  In two different implementations of dc, I am seeing float operations work without assigning via `k`.  I certainly remember the default precision being 0 (truncation to integer).  Am I mis-remembering, or is it simply that newer implementations have changed behavior?

Comment: I have only used `dc` rarely over the years since I'm more algebraic and less RPN so I don't remember. On a GNU system I'm using, the default is 0. An old (1993) FreeBSD [`man` page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dc&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+1.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) mentions the default being zero, but older BSD [`man` pages](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dc&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=2.9.1+BSD&arch=default&format=html) don't.

Comment: By the way (for future readers), my example should have shown non-integer *operands* instead of only a non-integer result in order to accurately counter the assertion. Never fear, `echo '4 k 50.5 7 / p' | dc` works (output: `7.2142`).

Answer (score 9):

A simple shell function (no `sed` needed) should do the trick of interpreting '5X5'

```
$ calc() { bc -l <<< ${*//[xX]/*}; }
$ calc 5X5
25
$ calc 5x5
25
$ calc '5*5'
25
```

Comment: Note that -- as described in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete -- the `function` keyword is a ksh-ism; the POSIX sh standard doesn't specify it, so the more portable way to write that would be `calc() { ...; }`. Also, using `$@` in a context that evaluates to a single string is a bit weird; consider `$*` in scenarios where you aren't expanding to an array (or otherwise multiple words).

Comment: Thanks for improving the quality of this answer, @Charles Duffy. I've amended my answer with your input.

Answer (score 7):

I use this function which uses `bc` and thus supports floating point calculations:

```
c () { 
    local a
    (( $# > 0 )) && a="$@" || read -r -p "calc: " a
    bc -l <<< "$a"
}
```

Example:

```
$ c '5*5'
25
$ c 5/5
1.00000000000000000000
$ c 3.4/7.9
.43037974683544303797
```

Bash's arithmetic expansion doesn't support floats (but Korn shell and zsh do).

Example:

```
$ ksh -c 'echo "$((3.0 / 4))"'
0.75
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a simple script I use for this:

`me@mycomputer:~$ cat /usr/local/bin/c`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$*" | sed 's/x/\*/g' | bc -l
```

It changes `x` to `*` since `*` is a special character in the shell.  Use it as follows:

- `c 5x5`
- `c 5-4.2 + 1`
- `c '(5 + 5) * 30'` (you still have to use quotes if the expression contains any parentheses).

Comment: I like your idea to use an "x" for multiplication. You could similarly use square brackets instead of parentheses to avoid the need for quoting. `tr` can be used to do character mapping for multiple characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you like python and have an option to install a package, you can use this [utility](https://github.com/bombs-kim/pythonp) that I made.

```bash
# install pythonp
python -m pip install pythonp

pythonp "5*5"
25

pythonp "1 / (1+math.exp(0.5))"
0.3775406687981454

# define a custom function and pass it to another higher-order function
pythonp "n=10;functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, range(1,n+1))"     
3628800
```