# Currency converter

Tags: bash

I'm stuck on this USD to SEK currency converter and the empty row, row 12. The current conversion is 1 SEK = 0.158193 USD   1 USD = 6.32138 SEK.

Row 12 will have something like SEK="(?(USD) )?"

I don't know what to enter in the question marks.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s -o nounset
declare -i USD # USD
declare -i SEK # SEK
# Title
printf "%s\n" "USD-SEK Currency Convertor"
printf "\n"
# Get the value to convert
read -p "Enter a USD: " USD
# Do the conversion

printf "You will get SEK %d\n" "$SEK"
exit 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiplication on command line terminal UNIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039876/multiplication-on-command-line-terminal-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do floating point arithmetic using `bc` like this:

```
SEK=$( echo " 6.32138 * $USD " | bc -l )
```

***Explanation:***

Bash does not have built it support for *floating point* arithmetic. Thus, we usually handle these operation using the `bc` program. `bc` reads an arithmetic expression as a string from the standard input, and prints the result the standard output. Note that the `-l` option is necessary for keeping the decimal part of the expression.

In order to get the result from `bc`, and store it in a variable, we use *command redirection* i.e. the `$(` `)`. Note that there are no spaces before and after the `=` in the previous expression.

***Complete Example***

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" "USD-SEK Currency Convertor"
# Get the value to convert
read -p "Enter a USD: " USD
SEK=$(echo " 6.32138 * $USD " | bc -l )
printf "You will get SEK %s\n" "$SEK"  ;#  NOTE THAT I CHANGED THIS TO %s FROM %f DUE TO THE LOCALE SETTINGS
```

***Output***

```
$ ./converter.sh 
USD-SEK Currency Convertor
Enter a USD: 10
You will get SEK 63.213800
```

*Note that i removed the `declare -i SEK` from the script, since the `SEK` variable is **NOT** Integer*

<s>The harm of `declare -i`. This code produces:</s>

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i SEK     ;#    WOOOPS I FORGOT THE declare -i
printf "%s\n" "USD-SEK Currency Convertor"
# Get the value to convert
read -p "Enter a USD: " USD
SEK=$(echo " 6.32138 * $USD " | bc -l )
printf "You will get SEK %s\n" "$SEK"
```

This output:

```
$ ./converter.sh 
USD-SEK Currency Convertor
Enter a USD: 10
./converter.sh: line 6: 63.21380: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".21380")
You will get SEK 0.000000
```

Comment: I tried this SEK="(1*(USD) )*6"

But if I want to use decimals after 6, I don't know how to declare it?

The same goes for your example, I get an syntax error.

6.32138

Comment: OK thanks, So I should change to %f in printf: %f(or %F)—Display a floating-point number without exponential notation

Comment: Yes also you should remove the `declare -i`

Comment: This is what I got when running the script:

USD-SEK Currency Convertor
Enter a USD: 10
./test2.sh: row 6: printf: 63.21380: invalid number
You will get SEK 0,000000

Comment: Was that before you changed to %f?

Comment: After, I ran your script as it is now.

Comment: Yes I validated it. This is caused by the `declare -i`. Could you check that you removed it? Just copy-paste the code from the answer and see if it runs in a new file.

Comment: Added example to show what happens if you leave the declaration in. It matches your output in that case

Comment: I ran your Complete Example and got that error code. Did a new file.

Comment: What I notice the difference with your output and mine is that your output is with a dot . and mine is with a comma.

You will get:

63.213800
I get a , after the first zero
0,000000

Comment: OK you have different locale settings. Give me a moment to see you we can resolve this

Comment: Running 12.10 VirtualBox, with GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: what is the output of `echo " 6.32138 * 10.0 " | bc -l` ?

Comment: If it is `63,21380` replace the `%f` in the `printf` with `%s` and you are done.

Comment: I removed printf and ran echo as declared. So that works. What was the issue with printf?

Comment: It expected I float number, but in your Locale, floats have a `,` as a decimal point. Thus, the string 63.2138 was an invalid float