# Bash program to convert currency

Tags: xml, bash, converters, currency

I need to make a simple bash currency converter. I need to read information from xml file. I've written xml file and i don't know what to do next. Any ideas?

XML file:

```
<rates>
<currency>
    <name>Australian dollar</name>
    <rate>2.34</rate>
    <amount>1</amount>
</currency>
<currency>
    <name>GB Pounds</name>
    <rate>4.12</rate>
    <amount>1</amount>
</currency>
<currency>
    <name>Euro</name>
    <rate>3.45</rate>
    <amount>1</amount>
</currency>
<currency>
    <name>USA dollar</name>
    <rate>2.55</rate>
    <amount>1</amount>
</currency>
<currency>
    <name>Russian ruble</name>
    <rate>7.72</rate>
    <amount>100</amount>
```

Comment: How do i use that xml code for this program? Do i copy same line for every rate? Or there is another way to do it? Help

Comment: Let's say i wanted to print names of every currency in columns? how would i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmllint to read values from the xml and then make the conversion

```
euro=$(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency[name="Euro"]/rate/text()' rates.xml)
echo $euro
```

Comment: Ok that helps. But how do i implement it so let's say i want to exchange 7 GB pounds to dollars?

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879133/currency-converter. And other idea... http://www.shell-fu.org/lister.php?id=821

Answer (score 0):

We know that you want to implement it in `bash`. However if possible, use `perl` or `python` for parsing `xml`. It has good liabraries for such tasks and it's easy to implement also.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible