# Bash Shell functions

Tags: bash

I have the following code inside a unix file with the name func.sh :

```
function sum {
var=$1
result=expr $var * 100
echo $result
}

export -f sum
```

I want to be able to call this function from command line hence i do this :

. ./func.sh

I check whether the function is properly exported or not with the below command :
declare -x -F

I can see the line : declare -fx sum

But i am unable to run the function from command line . It gives an error :

sum 10
-bash: 10: command not found

Can someone throw some light on what the issue is here ?

Comment: Maybe try `result=$((var * 100))`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add numbers in a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script), and [Multiplication in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039876/multiplication-on-command-line-terminal-unix).

Comment: Your don't need to export if your script just contain functions, just source it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the function correctly but a statement inside the function is causing the error.

You cant do:

`result=expr $var * 100`

You need to get the result of `expr` using subshell execution(`$()` recommended) or using backticks; its better to use `bash`'s `$(())` instead of calling an external process(expr)

```
$ function sum { var=$1; result=$(($var * 100)); echo $result; }
$ export -f sum
$ sum 10
1000
```

Comment: Also, capturing the output only to print it again is unnecessary; `function sum { expr "$1 * 100"; }` would do the same thing.